# Magick++ does not read Image

Tags: c++, cmake, magick++

In my first magick++ Project I am trying to read an image, rotate it and save it.

This is the source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std; 
using namespace Magick; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3)
   {
       printf("Usage: %s <Input file> <Output file>", argv[0]);
        return 1;
   }

   try{
        printf("Opening... %s\n", argv[1]);
        Magick::Image image(argv[1]);

        printf("Rotating...\n");
        image.rotate(45);

        printf("Opening... %s\n", argv[2]);
        image.write(argv[2]);
   }

   catch( Exception &error_ ) 
    { 
      cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl; 
      return 1; 
    } 
  return 0;
}
```

I compile the program with cmake (->msvc). It basically compiles fine, it just throws a lot of C4251 warnings of this form:

```
"Magick::PathMovetoRel::_coordinates": class "std::vector<Magick::Coordinate,std::allocator<Magick::Coordinate>>" erfordert eine DLL-Schnittstelle, die von Clients von class "Magick::PathMovetoRel" verwendet wird [C:\Users\jfi\Desktop\Hints_Scripts\InsortAP_Toolbox\VSCode\IMhelloworld_cmake\build\IMHelloWorld.vcxproj]
```

And one C4275 warning:

```
{
"resource": "/C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.9-Q8/include/Magick++/Exception.h",
"owner": "cmake-build-diags",
"code": "C4275",
"severity": 4,
"message": "class \"std::exception\" ist keine DLL-Schnittstelle und wurde als Basisklasse für die DLL-Schnittstelle class \"Magick::Exception\" verwendet [C:\\Users\\jfi\\Desktop\\Hints_Scripts\\InsortAP_Toolbox\\VSCode\\IMhelloworld_cmake\\build\\IMHelloWorld.vcxproj]",
"source": "MSVC",
"startLineNumber": 23,
"startColumn": 3,
"endLineNumber": 23,
"endColumn": 3
}
```

The program stops at reading the image. It does not give any errormessages.
Can I add some verbosity to magick++?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation

> Be sure to initialize the ImageMagick library prior to using the
>   Magick++ library. This initialization is performed by passing the path
>   to the ImageMagick DLLs (assumed to be in the same directory as your
>   program) to the InitializeMagick() function call. This is commonly
>   performed by providing the path to your program (argv[0]) as shown in
>   the following example:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char** argv)
> {
> InitializeMagick(*argv);
> ```

You aren't calling `InitializeMagick`

Comment: Still the same with 


InitializeMagick(*argv);


Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAEC3EC3F9 (msvcr120.dll) in IMHelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000A085B90000.

Comment: Not still the same, since you are now getting an error message. To me (but I'm no expert) that sounds like the image read has failed for some reason and so you are getting a crash when you try to rotate the image (or maybe when you write it). Use the error checking facilities that ImageMagick has to check for errors, never just assume that the code you write is going to work.